# dotnet SDK 2.2.104 don't compile .NET Core 2.2

Tags: .net-core, dotnet-cli, dotnet-sdk

1. I have a .NET Sdk version 2.1 and lower.
2. I installed sdk2.2 and sdk3.
3. I removed sdk3

Now, the VS17 build and test my solution successfully.

But from the command line, with dotnet-cli, I can't compile the solution, because he says he is `sdk2.1`.

**dotnet build**:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.500\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(137,5): error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.2.  Either target .NET Core 2.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.2. [C:\Users\.......\WebApi.csproj]

Build FAILED.
```

**dotnet --info**:

```
.NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   2.2.104
 Commit:    73f036d4ac

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.17763
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.104\

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 2.2.2
  Commit:  a4fd7b2c84

.NET Core SDKs installed:
  2.1.500 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  2.2.104 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

**WebApi.csproj**:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    .
    .
    .
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [livarcocc](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/10963#issuecomment-471596590), we know the issue is in `MSBuildSDKsPath` environment variable, who still points to `sdk2.1`.

For fix the problem, we need to retarget the `MSBuildSDKsPath` to the SDK version we want, or completely remove this variable.

**Before:**

```
set MSBuildSDKsPath
MSBuildSDKsPath=C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.500\Sdks
```

**After:**

```
set MSBuildSDKsPath
MSBuildSDKsPath=C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.104\Sdks
```